# Linq avoid calling function twice

Tags: c#, linq, anonymous-types

Using Linq to Objects a query might need to filter based on the result of a function and return the value of that function.

For example

```
files.Where(x => string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.getProperty(propName)))
                .GroupBy(x => x.getProperty(propName));
```

Does the compiler recognize that the value is going to be required for grouping and keep it?

If it doesn't then there must be a way to select to an anonymous type and query the Where and GroupBy statements against that. Is it possible to do this with an anonymous type?

I am able to declare a class and use that.

```
class fileSelector
{
    internal string prop;
    internal myFile file;
}

var groups = files
     .Select(x => new fileSelector() { prop = x.getProperty(propName),  file = x })
     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.prop))
     .GroupBy(x => x.prop);
```

But is there a way to do this with an anonymous type?

This is what I tried for an anonymous type

```
var groups = files.Select(x => new { x.getProperty(propName),  x })
                  .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.prop))
                  .GroupBy(x => x.prop);
```

But this gives the error

Invalid anonymous type member declarator. Anonymous type members must be declared with a member assignment, simple name or member access.

Final answer

```
var groups = files
     .Select(x => new { prop = x.getProperty(propName),  file = x })
     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.prop))
     .GroupBy(x => x.prop, x => x.file);
```

Comment: Did you tried that with anonymous type?

Comment: That's actually what `let` does when you use query syntax.  You probably want to change it to `GroupBy(x => x.prop, x => x.file)` so the items in the grouping are the items from `files` instead of your `fileSelector` class.

Comment: Fabio, see the edited portion at the end. juharr can you elaborate?

Comment: You have to give the first property of your anonymous class a name, and really should name the second as well `Select(x => new { prop = x.getProperty(propName), file = x })`

Comment: thanks, that makes sense

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Does the compiler recognize that the value is going to be required for grouping and keep it?

No, since `getProperty` might have an intended side effect.

> If it doesn't then there must be a way to select to an anonymous type and query the Where and GroupBy statements against that. Is it possible to do this with an anonymous type?

Yes. Your code should work as-it-is by just replacing `new fileSelector() {...}` with `new {...}`. Note, though, that in your code (and in the modified version using the anonymous type), the elements of the grouping are fileSelector and the anonymous type, not myFile. See [Scott Chamberlain's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38488545/87698) for how to fix that.

Alternatively, you could use [the `let` clause](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383976.aspx) to store intermediary values:

```
var groups = from file in files
             let prop = file.getProperty(propName)
             where !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(prop)
             group file by prop;
```

Comment: Keep that part in `{...}` as it is, i.e., `{ prop = x.getProperty(propName), file = x }`, not `{ x.getProperty(propName), x }`!

Comment: "*Your code should work as-it-is...*", there is one other thing he needs to fix, change the GroupBy to `.GroupBy(x => x.prop, x => x.file)` so he gets a `IGrouping<string, myFile>` instead of a `IGrouping<string, SomeAnnonamousType>`. The version you provide using query syntax and `let` already does that, correct? (I am not the best at query syntax)

Comment: @ScottChamberlain: Good point, I've added that to my answer. Yes, the query syntax does exactly that.

Answer (score 1):

> Does the compiler recognize that the value is going to be required for grouping and keep it?

No, it will touch the value twice.

You where actually quite close with your final example, you can do it with a annonamous type, just give names for each of the members of the anonymous type then add a element selector to make the body of the grouping the `file` property.

```
var groups = files
     .Select(x => new { prop = x.getProperty(propName), file = x })
     .Where(x => !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(x.prop))
     .GroupBy(x => x.prop, x => x.file);
```